# How to pass onClick function in sibling components using functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is the code link I want to implement the onClick function using sibling components.

I have two sibling components SignIn.js and SocialSignIn.js,

How could I implement them? Please help me.

[Sandbox code editor link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wilbur-08u3uy?file=/src/components/SignIn.js)

And also Code is here

```js
import { React } from "react";

// for Custom Email and Password Sign Up
const SignIn =({handleSocial})=>{

  return (

    <>
    <h2> this is sign in usiging 
    custom email & password</h2>
    {/* html form goes here  */}
    <button onClick={handleSocial}>social sign in</button>
    </>
  )
}
export default SignIn;


import { React } from "react";

//for social auth sign up
const SocialSignIn =()=>{
  const handleSocial = ()=>{
    console.log("hello social sign in")
  }
  return (
    <>
    <h2> this is social sign in</h2>
    </>
  )
}
export default SocialSignIn;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you need to render both of them at the same time?  Or one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You do not trigger your onclick, here the working version https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-tesla-x94ifr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Your App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import SocialSignIn from "./components/SocialSignIn.js";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SocialSignIn />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Signin.js

```
import { React } from "react";
const SignIn = ({ handleSocial }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    handleSocial();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2> this is sign in usiging custom email & password</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>social sign in</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default SignIn;
```

SocialSignIn.js

```
import { React } from "react";
import SignIn from "./SignIn";
const SocialSignIn = () => {
  const handleSocial = () => {
    console.log("hello social sign in");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h2> This is social sign in</h2>
      <SignIn handleSocial={handleSocial} />
    </>
  );
};
export default SocialSignIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use the `handleSocial` method from the `SocialSignIn` component inside of the `SignIn` component. This won't quite work how you expect it to as `handleSocial` is scoped solely for use inside of `SocialSignIn` and SocialSignIn is just a react component.

What you could be doing instead is using `SocialSignIn` as a child component within the `SignIn` component.

So `SignIn` component will have 2 flows:

- email/password flow
- social sign in flow, which is only shown if the user clicks a button.

You can set this up as such:

```js
import { React } from "react";

// for Custom Email and Password Sign Up
const SignIn =()=>{
const [showSocialLogin, setShowSocialLogin] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
    {!showSocialLogin && 
      <div>
        <h2> this is sign in usiging 
        custom email & password</h2>
        {/* html form goes here  */}
        <button onClick={() => setShowSocialLogin(true)}>Click here for social login</button>
      </div>
    }
    {showSocialLogin && <SocialSignIn onCancel={() => setShowSocialLogin(false)} />}
    </>
  )
}
export default SignIn;


import { React } from "react";

//for social auth sign up
const SocialSignIn =({onCancel})=>{
  return (
    <>
    <h2> this is social sign in</h2>
    <button onClick={props.onCancel}>Go back to email/password</button>
    </>
  )
}
export default SocialSignIn;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```